# Order of execution of ORDER BY and LIMIT in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit, sql-execution-plan

I have a query like this where I want to display sorted records in a paginated format.

This is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM answers
WHERE userid = '10'
ORDER BY votes LIMIT 10, 20
```

The two arguments to `LIMIT` will be used for generating page-by-page display of records. Now, my problem is `ORDER BY`. How does MySQL execute this query?

1st way

- Select the records according to filters
- Sort them
- Limit them

2nd way

- Select the records according to filters
- Limit them
- Sort them

If I think like MySQL engine, I would want to implement 2nd, since I would then have to sort lesser records?

Can somebody throw some light on this?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A SQL *LIMIT* will in all databases always work on the result of a query, so it will run the query with the *ORDER BY* and that result will then be limited. This is a functional requirement, the database not perse needs to execute it like that.

Thus the 1st way.

Comment: That proves I need practice thinking like MySQL :)

Answer (score 2):

Mysql follows the 1st way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your 2nd way, try using a subquery with the limit, then order.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM answers
  WHERE userid = '10'
  LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY votes
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st way as mentioned by the last two answers. From a user perspective, the 2nd way won't be very useful anyways.